# Why aren't Martian Manhunter and Green Lantern in Justice League (2017) movie?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league, justice-league-2017

I can't imagine Justice League without Martian Manhunter and Green Lantern. My emotions are attached with this:

[image]

But, I am getting this:

[image]

Why did producers choose to not include Martian Manhunter and Green Lantern (they were also part of original seven members of Justice League in comics) in the movie?

Comment: So you don't care about Hawkgirl :(

Comment: Because Ryan Reynolds is Deadpool now.

Comment: I'd read something that JJ/MM was likely not included as "*he is an Alien, last of his race, misunderstood and trying to do good*" (OWTTE). Sound like another guy dressed in Red and Blue in the film? The interests would've clashed etc.

Comment: “I can't imagine Justice League without Martian Manhunter and Green Lantern.” Now you don’t have to! They made a movie to show you exactly what it’s like!

Comment: I strongly suspect it's because there are three white males, three non-white characters, a woman and a black guy (who's also disabled). Adding in more characters would have thrown off the demographic pattern

Comment: I suggest it is because they are looking at the New 52 justice league.
Which is I think that exact set of heroes. But I'm not sure, I've only just started reading the new 52 aquaman, (which has that justice league in it). (Edit: ah @CBredlow got their first)

Comment: @PaulDWaite and by early reports, it’s awful. But I don’t think “more CGI” to make GL work would be an improvement

Comment: @Valorum Adding GL and MM wouldn't have disrupted demographic balance. Hal Jordan GL is white and MM is obviously non-white (and, anyone could be picked for his human form).

Comment: @Valorum  I'm a little surprised to hear you think demographics are that important to that mix. Mostly, though, this is because I didn't notice/know Gadot (Israeli) or Momoa (mixed white + native Hawaiian) were considered non-white.

Comment: @Discovery - Demographic are very important when considering who you target your marketing (which might end up costing 50% or more of the cost of the film) at. Having the right [demo mix](http://i.imgur.com/YskcNjF.jpg) is very important.

Comment: @kaine - There's a strong tendency in Hollywood to favour actors who are just foreign enough to tick the "not white" box. but are also pretty damn white. It gets them the best of both worlds, hence why an overwhelming number of top billing black actresses are actually mixed-race and often with very pale skin.

Comment: No Lantern because people are still recovering from that [train wreck](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/green_lantern/)

Comment: "I can't imagine Justice League without Martian Manhunter ..." Not difficult for me; back when I read the comics in the mid- to late 1970's, Martian Manhunter (almost?) never appeared.

Comment: @Valorum Are you saying Cyborg is *disabled*? I guess he technically does have prosthetic limbs...

Comment: @KSmarts - That is entirely how they're marketing him; [*“I’ve had lots of fans who come out and say ‘Listen, I can relate to Cyborg because I lost a limb,’ or ‘I have this cochlear implant.’ It’s one of those things when you actually start seeing it, when you actually start hearing about it, that made Cyborg more relevant to me than I think he ever had been up until that point.”*"](https://screenrant.com/justice-league-zack-snyder-cyborg-representation-disabilities/)

Comment: @Valorum   Teen Titans episode "Sum of his Parts" - kid with prosthetic arm explains to Cyborg how he looks up to him as a result of their similar circumstance. Its heartwarming but shows your point. I miss that show.

Comment: Don't forget, there is *A* Green Lantern in JL - we see one fighting in the original battle against Steppenwolf. His identity is in question, but there's a consensus it's Yalan Gur, an ancient Corpsman who appeared in the comics in 1991. ( https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183619/which-green-lantern-appears-in-justice-league/183626#183626 ). If someone told me there was also a Martian or even a Saturnian in that crowd, I'd have no evidence to disagree.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Green Lantern

GL's non-presence was discussed with the studio's bigwigs (Greg Silverman, president of creative development Warner Bros and DC producer Charles Roven) in an interview with Entertainment Weekly. They claim that it's down to three reasons;

- That Green Lantern is too important a character to simply *turn up* in an ensemble film.
- That they already have something Green Lantern-related in the works (presumably their slated 2020 "[Green Lantern corps](http://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/green-lantern-corps/46480/green-lantern-corps-david-goyer-rumoured-to-direct)" movie).
- That introducing *even more characters* would be confusing for audiences.

> *“[Green Lantern] is an incredible character. He’s actually multiple
> incredible characters,” Silverman says. “There’s real opportunity
> there. We didn’t do a great job on that first Green Lantern movie.
> This is a character who deserves to be treated in the same way that
> Batman and Superman and Wonder Woman are being treated now, which is
> with great reverence. I guess I can say to the Green Lantern fans: if
> they can be patient with us, I think they’ll be really happy.”*
>
> *But how patient? Roven says we may not see Hal Jordan, John Stewart,
> or any incarnation of Green Lantern until Justice League – Part Two.
> Maybe. “Every beat of the movie is not yet worked out. So there’s the
> possibility that he may or may not be in Justice League 2,” the
> producer says. “For now, we felt that we were introducing enough
> characters that the best possible place we could put Green Lantern is
> some introduction in Justice League 2, or barring that, a movie
> after.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice links the DC Comics movie universe](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/03/03/batman-v-superman-dawn-justice-green-lantern-dc-movie-universe/3/)</sup></sub>

---

### Martian Manhunter

Senior DC scriptwriter David Goyer spoke about Martian Manhunter not being in the film in a [Scriptnotes podcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/scriptnotes-podcast/id462495496?mt=2). He broke it down into four main reasons. It's probably fair to say that if he's speaking openly, that these are prevalent beliefs within the upper echelons of DC's movie team.

- The Martian Manhunter is too much of an unknown with audiences (and that they were happy to licence him to Supergirl for next-to-nothing for precisely that reason).
- That his name is "*goofy*" and stupid-sounding.
- That he's almost impossible to use in an ensemble film without a long back-story explaining his existence.
- That his back-story is actually kinda dumb.

> Martian Manhunter, AKA J'onn J'onzz, is of course the last survivor of
> an ancient Martian civilization, notable for being one of the
> cofounders of the Justice League of America. He has not been announced
> to appear in the upcoming Justice League film however, and based on
> what Goyer said when asked about the character, it's looking like he
> likely won't. After first dismissing Martian Manhunter as too obscure
> to matter, Goyer explained how he can't see making use of the
> character without removing nearly everything associated with the
> character. I'll just let his words speak for themselves:
>
> *"He can't be fucking called the Martian Manhunter because that's
> goofy. He can be called Manhunter... The whole deal with Martian
> Manhunter is he's an alien living amongst us... So he comes down to
> Earth and decides, unlike Superman who already exists in the world
> now, that he's just going to be a homicide detective... So instead of
> using super-powers and mind-reading and like, oh, I could figure out
> if the President's lying or whatever, he just decides to disguise
> himself as a human homicide detective. Dare to dream!"*
>
> *"I would set it up like The Day After Tomorrow. We discover one of
> those Earth-like planets... So maybe like... we get the DNA code from
> that planet and then grow him in a petri dish here... He's like in
> Area 51 or something and we're just basically... doing biopsies on
> him."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Goyer's Martian Manhunter Comments Are Why DC Can't Have Nice Things](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/134697-Goyers-Martian-Manhunter-Comments-Are-Why-DC-Cant-Have-Nice-Things)</sup></sub>

Comment: "*We didn’t do a great job on that first Green Lantern movie. This is a character who deserves to be treated in the same way that Batman and Superman…*" but why do the DC movies hate Green Lantern so much that they'd do that to him? Again.

Comment: If this is how senior management at DC movies feels about the Martian Manhunter, then I for one am happy they won't be including him. If the character is going to be in a movie, it should be written by someone who appreciates and understand the character.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I agree. He is such an awesome character.

Comment: *"his name is "goofy" and stupid-sounding."* Yeesh.  With this line of reasoning Guardians of the Galaxy wouldn't be the same - can you imagine it without rocket raccoon?  Once the character was established everyone loved it and the name is now positive.  They make fun of that very trope with the whole "taser face" sequence - it doesn't matter what the name is.  Perception will be created based on how it's used.  Rocket was able to create a negative impression where none previously existed. If DC treats the character well, it doesn't (within limits) matter what the name is.

Comment: @AdamDavis  - GotG is intended to be a light-hearted sci-comedy so it's ok to have silly characters doing silly things. Justice League may have funny moments, but it's intended to be a serious superhero fantasy film

Comment: @Valorum Ah yes, the "grimdark" aesthetic. Perhaps you're right, and DC is severely limited in their ability to include their own characters in their own movies due to this decision. I suspect, though, that a great writer and a great director could make it work even with this aesthetic. Regardless, while I still believe it's a silly reason, there are plenty of other reasons that are valid, so it's not a point worth debating, I just wanted to point out that this particular reason is very weak.

Comment: It is also possible that, like me, some of the decision-makers are old enough to remember the [1970s cartoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Friends#The_Justice_League_of_America) rather than the [newer ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series)).

Comment: @AdamDavis - Note that Marvel actually had a character in the 1990s Guardians comic, called Taserface. Rocket was not involved there.

Comment: Superman, Batman, and Wonder Woman already introduced in the movies (the ones DC isn't embarrassed over); Flash has his own TV show; Aquaman is well-known even if you didn't watch the *Justice League* cartoon, or *Super Friends*. Cyborg can be introduced easily (and his latest origin tied into the start of the JL anyway), and is known from the *Teen Titans* cartoons from the past decade-plus. Hawkgirl replaced Aquaman in the JL cartoon (presumably to include more females). Note how Manhunter was introduced in the JL cartoon - that three-parter *was* his origin there. He is complicated....

Comment: @AdamDavis To be fair, at no point is Rocket actually called "Rocket Raccoon" in either GotG 1 or 2, he just goes by "Rocket" with some raccoon jokes made now and then.

Comment: Re "grimdark": Perhaps if DC stopped trying to make the same mediocre movie over and over again, they would succeed in not making the same mediocre movie over and over again.

Comment: @Steam Yeah, that's a good caveat. DC could certainly use "Manhunter" alone.

Comment: They managed things pretty well on *Supergirl*. He doesn’t disguise himself as a homicide detective - he disguises himself as an agent for a force that defends Earth against extraterrestrial invasions (and becomes the leader of that organization). Of course, he’s uniquely qualified for that. This preserves the basic element of him disguising himself as a law enforcement officer.

Comment: He doesn’t make himself publicly known a la Supergirl (initially), because the people who killed virtually all of his species are still out there, and he doesn’t want to get their attention.

Comment: And you don’t call him “The Martian Manhunter” or even “Manhunter,” you call him “J’onn J’onzz,” which actually looks pretty alien and sounds perfectly fine (especially if you just call him “J’onn” virtually all of the time).

Comment: And finally, while audiences do want to see big explosions and epic battles and whatever, and I understand that, I would point out that there’s nothing ridiculous about using one’s mind-reading powers for police work. No wrongful convictions on one’s record, an extremely high conviction rate, catching probably hundreds of criminals that no one else would even spot…. Of course, it most certainly is an invasion of privacy, but it’s not improbable for someone who wants to help people, and there nothing *small* about it.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Yeah but that clearly hasn't stopped them from making any of these other DC movies.

Answer (score 12):

Their powers are CGI heavy and would be very costly to animate correctly.

Martian Manhunter is a shapeshifter. Take away his shapeshifting and you basically have a green guy with super strenght with mind reading powers. And he has back story of Superman (as noted by Edlothiad). So,slightly stronger Aquaman.

Green Lantern is shapeshifting on steroids. A green guy that projects magical light that moves and cuts and punches things? Heavy CGI. But the guy that occasionally fires his hand cannon and is half robot? Much more limited and easier to animate and fix with costumer. Thus, Cyborg.

As for Hawkgirl? She is Wonder Woman with mace and wings. Winged flight is hard to animate correctly, because everyone has seen birds flying before and knows how it looks like. Otherwise, you get this:

In terms of story and what they bring on the table in terms of action and cost to actually bring it on screen, they are too expensive and they're not unique enough. I always felt it was that way during shows run as well.
Hawkgirl, what does she do? She is a girl that flies around and punches things. Wonder Woman? Ditto.
In fact, most of the original JLA powers are "flies around and punches things". Superman has eyebeams and x-ray vision in addition, but he rarely uses them. GL used his ring to mostly fly around and punch things and occasional protective barrier. MM used his powers to shift through walls, fly around and punch things.

Comment: This seems like really bad speculation at best without any form of support to back this statement.

Comment: @Edlothiad He seems correct. I just checked budgets. Green Lantern's budget was whopping 200 million USD. In comparison, Avengers 220 million USD.

Comment: @Discovery Green Latern also had dozens of these people needing animation. There's no reason to suggest that's any more than speculation. jo1storm, stealing ideas without even a hint of saying where you got it from his pretty harsh.

Comment: Green Lantern's budget was so high because they needed to do extensive reshoots and a long re-edit. If it was a competent film, it would have cost under $150M to make

Comment: And I will ask you, sir, to stay away from insulting the fine cinematography that went into Flash Gordon, one of the best examples of cinema in the last fifty years.

Comment: It's not insulting, I just wanted to show Hawkgirl's people in all their glory. I use every opportunity to spread the blessing of Brian Blessed.

Comment: "Martian Manhunter is a shapeshifter. Take away his shapeshifting and you basically have a green guy with super strength with mind reading powers." Uh, did you forget that he also has psychic ice-cream-making powers?

Comment: You just forgot about the power that makes Martian Manhunter almost invincible: Intangibility. That makes him almost unique within that universe.

Comment: Not really true. He got zapped multiple times while "intangible". But it goes with shapeshifting, he shapeshifts into mist/ghost who can walk through most walls. Also a power that would need to be animated by CGI.

Comment: @jo1storm, well, a ghost that walks through walls is basically the easiest possible special effect to do.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of reasons I can think of off the top of my head.

The green lantern movie tanked, it sank without trace. My wifes reaction to it was "So his power is he can manifest anything he can imagine as long as he concentrates? How can anyone stand against him when he could just imagine velociraptors with machine-guns?".
<s>I doubt you'll see the green lantern on screen for another decade, at least.</s>
Apparently a Green Lanatern movie is in the works! o_O

Also, this is an ensemble movie, we have three known entities (WW, BM & SM) who need to get along & interact etc. They're adding two new characters, who - within the run time of the movie - need to be introduced, we've to get to know them & their powers, and we've to find how they fit into the existing & still evolving dynamic between BM, SM & WW.
I honestly don't think there's room in the movie to introduce more new - and massively powered - characters.

If you compare this to Avengers Assemble, Marvel hardly introduced a new character in that movie, all the avengers & the main villain had appeared on screen before, Clint Barton had the least screen time having had only a small cameo in Thor.
All the super heroes had hours of screen time before being teamed up.

Here we have three fully fleshed characters, with movie time under their belts, but we've to do the narrative work to introduce two more while still telling a coherent story.

Comment: Remember they've also got an Aquaman solo film lined up so he was pretty essential.

Comment: There may be a movie lined up, but the cogitative load for the audience is in _this_ movie, "Who is he", "Where does he come from?", "Why is he here now?", "Where was he was New York was being flattened by alien powers?", "Why do I care?" are all the questions an audience needs to have satisfactory answers to, and they all have to be answered in _this_ movie. Now add the same questions for The Flash, and this movie has a lot of work to do before we can all start having "fun"

Comment: Oh I 100% agree, I'm saying his inclusion as opposed to MM or GL is also because they need to set up his introduction for a strong solo-film. They couldn't just have a bunch of other people in this JL team and then out of nowhere drop a random stand-alone film from a lesser known character.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Gotcha

Comment: “while still telling a coherent story” — this did not appear to be a requirement for the previous DC Extended Universe movies :/

Comment: They've already slated a $150m+ Green Lantern film for 2020; https://screenrant.com/green-lantern-corps-hal-jordan-john-stewart-confirmed/

Comment: Just because your wife thinks that GL sucks, you can't say he sucks for everyone. I am a big fan.

Comment: @Discovery: I liked it too, her reaction, and that of many who don't know the source material was pretty negative. It barely broke even at the box office, meaning that for the studio it didn't make a profit making it a failure financially. Critically it was almost universally panned too (getting only 26% on Rotten Tomatoes). Now there are movies I love that are - subjectively - appallingly bad, and that's OK. The Green Lantern was a commercial and critical failure, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't love it.

Comment: You mention The Avengers (Avengers Assemble) having mostly established characters. In my opinion, that was also the main reason that Age of Ultron was a much weaker film. Introducing and trying to make us care about Ultron, Pietro, Wanda, and Vision while giving the established characters their share of time *and* having a lot of action was just too much to do.

Comment: Your definitely right about the number of new characters in each movie being a problem but you may give them to much credit seeing as how they did suicide squad I don't think that the studio sees introduction times as a problem.

Comment: OK, but now I really want to see GL summoning velociraptors with machine guns...