# Which Green Lantern appears in Justice League?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, green-lantern, justice-league-2017

In the 2017 film *Justice League*, the audience sees a flashback detailing how the races of the world banded together to defeat Steppenwolf of Apokolips. Amazons, Atlanteans, Gods, and even a Green Lantern all participate in the battle. The Green Lantern is promptly killed, and his ring floats away. Is the Green Lantern we see a pre-existing character from the comics, or was it created just for the movie?

Comment: Related question from sister site [What were all the fighters in previous Age of Heroes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82796/what-were-all-the-fighters-in-previous-age-of-heroes) and [Are there additional hints of Green Lantern?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82858/are-there-additional-hints-of-green-lantern)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Yalan Gur (or a member of the same species)

The alien Green Lantern in the flashback resembles [Yalan Gur](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Yalan_Gur), who first appeared in *Green Lantern* #19 (December, 1991), and who operated on Earth (and throughout [Sector 2814](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Sector_2814)) in the [10th Century](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Yalan_Gur_(New_Earth)).

[image: Justice League (2017)]

[image: Green Lantern Yalan Gur]

(Image comparison: [Justice League – Film Review & The Ultimate Case](https://saminaik.com/2018/02/17/justice-league-film-review-the-ultimate-case/))

Note the cape, the enlarged mouth, and the red skin on the movie Lantern's legs and forearms.

A different angle shows that the film Green Lantern's teeth closely resemble Yalan Gur's teeth:

[image: Yalan Gur, showing teeth]

In the comics, Yalan Gur died in disgrace, having abused his power.  The Green Lantern in the film, however, died a heroic death.  It may be that this is the same character, with different personal histories in the two portrayals.  Another possibility is that these are different individuals of the same species.  Over time, the Green Lantern Corps (in the comics) has recruited more than one member<sup>(1)</sup> from some species.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> [Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Green_Lanterns):

- Korugarian: Thaal Sinestro, Katma Tui, and the half-Korugarian Soranik Natu
- Xudarian: Tomar-Re, Tomar-Tu, and Somar-Le
- Human: almost too many to count

---

**Long lifespans**

Some of DC Comics' species — such as the Guardians and Larfleeze's people — live longer than *planets*, with natural lifespans measuring billions of years. According to [*Action Comics* 1000](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/action-comics-2016/action-comics-1000) (2018), even humans from our time (such as Lois Lane) are alive and well five billion years from now, thanks to medicine.

Yalan Gur could be from another such long-lived species, or from one with a relatively short lifespan (say, a mere 100,000 years) that is nevertheless sufficient to encompass the 10th Century and the battle several tens of thousands of years earlier.

Comment: I never thought there could be an answer to the question.. +1

Comment: Great details. But I guess you missed the fact that Steppenwolf invaded Earth about 30,000 years ago (according to the movie's plot). That's like 28000 B.C. So the GL may well be someone else from Yalgun's species but not actually him.

Comment: @Shreedhar - Some species — such as the Guardians and Larfleeze's people — have natural lifespans measuring billions of years.  Yalan Gur could be from another such long-lived species.

Comment: Why is that illustration done in such a weird style?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd That was one of the last (if not the last) published comics by Martin Nodell, creator of the original Golden Age Green Lantern. He had a very loose, old school style, which only got looser.  Noted Flash artist Carmine Infantino has a similar change to his art as time went on.

Comment: If Yalan gur was in the 10th century in the Comics it could not have been  the same GL in the movie clip because that was around 20,000 years previous of the Yalan Gur from the comics, @Gaultheria.