# Which Green Lantern is seen in the nightmare scene from Zack Snyder's Justice League?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In *Zack Snyder's Justice League (2021)*, when the Justice League are at the Kryptonian ship trying to resurrect Kal-El, Cyborg has some sort of vision/dream of the future:

In this vision, Cyborg sees that

> Darkseid has defeated the League and kills Wonder Woman, Aquaman (and also others). Superman is seen floating in the sky with a dead Green Lantern in the foreground (*image below*): 
>
>
>  [image: Cyborg's vision JL Snyder Cut]
>   <sub>*Cyborg's vision JL Snyder Cut (click image to enlarge)*</sub>

The only GL appearing in the movies was [Yalan-Gur](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/183626/92306), but it couldn't have been him since he died during the first attempted invasion and the vision was about the future. Also, all other human Lanterns (Hal Jordan, John Stewart, Guy Gardner, etc.) can be ruled out since this GL clearly isn't human.

So, which Green Lantern is seen here?

Comment: Probably Abin Sur?

Answer (score 5):

There's no official confirmation, but [most](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowog#Live_action) [sites](https://screenrant.com/the-two-green-lanterns-in-zack-snyders-justice-league-explained/) [tend to](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kilowog) [agree](https://comicbook.com/dc/news/zack-snyders-justice-leagues-green-lanterns-explained/) that it's [Kilowog](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Kilowog).

The below image (taken from [cbr.com](https://www.cbr.com/justice-league-snyder-cut-knightmare-trivia-details/)) has been lightened, and you can see a resemblance. There are differences in skin tone and body build, but the face is pretty spot on.

[image]